# Web Scraping Macro error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrap multiple pages that are a search result of a key work.
I wrote this code but I am getting an error when I run it. Error:

```
Application \-defined or object-defined error.
```

When I click debug it points me to the following line:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

Code:

```
Sub adds()

For x = 1 To 3

Worksheets("sheet1").Select

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

mystr = "URL;http://apps.webofknowledge.com.ezproxy1.lib.asu.edu/Search.do?product=WOS&SID=1BzJbqm9xDW5Yzj4rhB&search_mode=GeneralSearch&prID=44dc4b3a-138a-4532-8429-772860bea673"

mystr = Cells(x, 1)

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))

'.CommandType = 0

.Name = _
        "http://apps.webofknowledge.com.ezproxy1.lib.asu.edu/Search.do?product=WOS&SID=1BzJbqm9xDW5Yzj4rhB&search_mode=GeneralSearch&prID=44dc4b3a-138a-4532-8429-772860bea673"

.FieldNames = True

.RowNumbers = False

.FillAdjacentFormulas = False

.PreserveFormatting = True

.RefreshOnFileOpen = False

 .BackgroundQuery = True

.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells

.SavePassword = False

.SaveData = True

.AdjustColumnWidth = True

.RefreshPeriod = 0

.WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage

.WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone

.WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True

.WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True

.WebSingleBlockTextImport = False

.WebDisableDateRecognition = False

.WebDisableRedirections = False

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use your variable `mystr` in this line -

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

`mystr = "URL;http://apps.webofknowledge.com.ezproxy1.lib.asu.edu/Search.do?product=WOS&SID=1BzJbqm9xDW5Yzj4rhB&search_mode=GeneralSearch&prID=44dc4b3a-138a-4532-8429-772860bea673"`

But then you **redefine** it *before* calling it in the `querytables.add` method -

`mystr = Cells(x, 1)`

So, now it's

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Cells(x, 1), Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```

Unless cells(x,1) has the correct format for the `querytables.add` method, it won't know what to do.

You also haven't seemed to declare any of your variables, so I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: That was helpful, Thank you. Can you tell me how to make it store all the results in one tab till its filled then start another tab?

Comment: @haytham if this was helpful, then you need to upvote the question as I have!

Comment: @haytham that would need to be a separate question, I think. If this one is solved, please hit the green checkmark to mark it as such. You can always refer back to it if you have an additional question